# Define separate XAML layouts based on screen orientation

Tags: xaml, user-interface, win-universal-app

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/layouts-with-xaml, you can set separate XAML layout pages based on device family. However, I've built my app in such a way that the family doesn't really matter (it renders well on phones, desktops, and laptops). What DOES matter is the orientation; certain things need to moved around based on whether the screen is in portrait or landscape mode.

Currently I'm using a work-around where I catch the page resized event in code, check the new orientation, and move things manually. However, it would be much easier if I could just write two separate XAML pages, one for portrait, and one for landscape. Then I wouldn't need to worry about catching the resized event.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can use custom triggers to set different UI depending on orientation. Refer this link http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/uwp-adaptive-layout-best-practices-part-i-adaptive-triggers. There is code for custom orientation trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Use `VisualStateTrigger`, create your own custom trigger OR use this library:

https://github.com/dotMorten/WindowsStateTriggers